# Converting to .exe don’t present the correct output

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to get the wireless SSID and add the priority order next to it.
It should look something like this

```
1   SSID    work
2   SSID    home
3   SSID    TEST
```

I have done the following

```
Set /a c=0
netsh wlan show profile >temp
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('find  "All User Profile" temp') do call :processline %%a
goto :END
goto :eof
:processline
set /a c=c+1
echo.  %c%         %*
goto :eof
:eof
```

Its seem to work OK, but when I compile the program to an executable doesn’t work anymore
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Okay, managed to solve my issue. Now it also works when it compiles to exe.

```
netsh wlan show profile >temp

for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ('find  "All User Profile" temp') do (
echo.  !x!            %%i
set /a x=!x!+1
)
```